# Spring 3 validation (JSR-303) @Min

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am trying to validate an input field that is supposed to contain (if not empty) a natural number (i.e. a positive non-zero integer: 1, 2, 3, ....)

I am using the following annotations:

```
@Digits(integer=10, fraction=0)
@Min(value = 1)
private Long number;
```

(Is this the best way to describe my constraint???)

When I submit a number such as 1.5 I get a **VALIDATION MESSAGE** which is good.
However when I submit an input such as -1 I do not get any VALIDATION MESSAGE. What do I miss?

Thanks!

P.S. Since my (other) Hibernate annotations for this field were on the getter of the field, I just move these two annotations to the getter as well (instead of being on the actual field). Did not help.

**EDIT**

I just read I might need to add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to my XML. I did it, however while starting the server I am getting the exception:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]`

I am not sure what it means and if I actually need (????) that annotation-driven tag... also, if I needed that annotation-driven tag in my xml, why did my other annotations (including one of the validation annotations) work without it?

Answer (score 3):

You do need the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag. That's what tells Spring Web MVC to activate JSR-303 validation.

A few things to check:

1) Make sure you declare the `mvc` namespace prefix in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` config. For example (using Spring 3 here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    ...
</beans>
```

2) Also make sure you have the Spring Web MVC JAR on your classpath. The JAR contains the namespace handler, which is the thing that knows how to process MVC configuration namespace.

3) Be sure that Hibernate Validator is on the classpath. Spring needs it in order to perform the validation.

As to your question of why your other annotations worked: `<mvc:annotation-driven>` isn't responsible for all annotations, just some of them. One thing it is responsible for is JSR-303 validations, as noted above.

Regarding why your other validation worked, my guess is that it wasn't a validation that worked at all. Instead, when you try to put 1.5 into a `Long`, Spring can't do it, and you're probably getting an error message of some sort. I don't think you need the `@Digits` annotation here at all. If you remove it, I'm guessing you'll still get the message.

Comment: Thanks! I have actually had (1) (2) (3). What I had to change was the jars: I've changed all my Spring jars from 3.0.0 to 3.0.5 and the @Min is now working. Thank you for the explanation about why the @Min did work. You are right about `@Digits` not being required... 1. but what is the mechanism that gives me the (rather nice) error message instead of seeing the exception stack trace? 2. How can I change the error message e.g. for Integer. 3. what is the usual practice for validating one of the primitives? No need of any specific annotation as is the case with Integer?

Comment: 4. It's not always clear what annotations are supposed to do: convert the input to the correct format (if possible), e.g. convert 1.5 to 1 when the bean is expecting to get an Integer; or reject the input when it does not match (like with @Min).
E.g.: `@NumberFormat` seems to accept numbers that do not match the pattern, and simply convert them to the right pattern. While `@DateTimeFormat` rejects dates that do not match the pattern nad outputs an error message. Even though they are both Spring annotations (not JSR-303). I would appreciate any explanation and/or reference to relevant webpages.

Answer (score 1):

You have to additionally explicitly specify Spring to validate your bean at the point of binding using [@Valid](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-triggering) annotation, can you confirm you are doing this. I am assuming the error that you are getting with 1.5 as the input is simply because 1.5 cannot be put into a Long field and is a binding exception, not a validation exception.

Comment: I have of course specified the @Valid annotation on my command object. My Controller's method looks like this: `public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @Valid Book book, BindingResult result) throws Exception {...}` And NO, the error message I am getting is from the `@Digits` validation, not a binding exception. Without any validation being used, if I enter a negative integer number (e.g. -1), it acts as if I entered nothing (which is OK and what I expected). The weird thing is that with these two annotations, only the `@Digits` works.

Comment: I saw your second edit, that error is because you need spring-webmvc jar(3.0+) in your classpath. mvc:annotation-driven is required, it causes the validator for JSR303 to be loaded up as a bean. Additionally in my local projects I have validation-api jar and hibernate's implementation hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar also present.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed all my Spring jars from 3.0.0 to 3.0.5 and I @Min is working now. See above my comments to Willie Wheeler.

Answer (score 0):

If its an integer, why not make it an `Integer`?  Also, it should be `@Min(1)`.

Comment: I meant integer in the mathematical sense. It can be larger than `Integer` so I am using `Long`. I think `@Min(1)` is just an abbreviation, anyway Eclipse suggests `@Min(value = )`.